# Impedance determination of blackbox circuit

Tags: impedance

I've been looking into something and I'm not entirely sure how this is done.

So I was looking at how they determine the parasitic and resistive components in pv panels, it looks like the majority of studies I've found use impedance spectroscopy. Although the general form of the circuit is known, i.e. we know the electrical circuit equivalent of a circuit can be modelled as either the one or two diode model with the parasitic capacitance and inductance added on.

My question is when you have some circuit, where you have no idea what the electrical representation is, how do they determine it? How was say the one diode model of a pv panel determined?

Not sure if this is very basic and I've just completely whoosed something.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting to know an unknown black box, usually a theoretical model called linear system theory (LST) is used.

LST states that if connect a sinusoidal input voltage with a fixed frequency to a black box, you will get a sinusoidal input current with the same frequency, but with a certain amplitude and a certain phase. This also means that with a black box of type LST system, you will not get another frequency out than the stimulating input. (This can be used to test if the sytem is an LST one).

From this measurements (amplitude and phase of current) you can then extract the electrical parameters, namely resistance R, inductance L and capacitance C within that black box.

Unfortunately, a diode is a nonlinear device and thus can not be modeled with LST.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the answer, I appreciate it, so I've done some more reading and it looks like all of this falls under system identification? I'm still not too sure how the complete circuit is determined, but this is a start to learn a bit more! Do you have any resources you would recommend for non-linear system identification & introductory resources? Thanks again for taking the time. I really appreciate it

Comment: My answer only covers linear time-invariant systems. Yes, I think system identification is a good term for further research. If you want to learn more concerning the basics of linear time-invariant system theory, you will find a lot of lecture scripts on the internet like e.g. https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/78864/LinearTI_Dynamic_Systems.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y